# Is Intersection at Compile Time for Java useful?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac, intersection

The Java standard allows the manipulation of the AST at compile time. However there is no standard about the API and every compiler implements it differently (even between versions). At work we used to had some hack mixing compile time and load time intersection. We now are changing into a eclipse focused development process and this hack is giving us some trouble.

I wrote a JVM Agent that loads a Javassist transformer and rewrites the bytecode, removing the need of compile time intersection, and solving our problems.

My question is: Is Intersection at Compile Time for Java useful? Is there a use case in which you can't do it using intersection at load time?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Do you mean "introspection"?

Comment: No, looking into the meta representation of your code is called Reflection. Change it is called intersection.

Comment: Do you have any description link about this meaning of *intersection*? I didn't hear the name before, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection) doesn't list it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt sound to smart to commit to a non public API. What happens when it changes, because there is no public commitment by publishing an API ?

Add a post compile step and use ASM.

Comment: The idea is to create a library that abstracts that private API and avoid using post compile manipulation. Each change you only need to create a translator for that version.